# Power series with double zeros

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, power-series

How many power series of the form
$1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}x^{k}$ with $a_{k}\in \{-1,0,1 \}$, that have a double zero $f(x)=f'(x)=0$ in $(0,1)$, are there. Ok, there are many ways to understand the question: set theoretical, topological, measure theoretical. I would be especially interested in the Bernoulli measures of the coefficient space $C\subseteq \{-1,0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ of such series.

Comment: Is it known whether there is a *polynomial* of this kind with a double zero in $(0,1)$?

Comment: @Noam Nice question! I gave it a quick stab, looking for a double root at $(\sqrt{5}-1)/2$. The LLL found no solutions with degree $\leq 30$.

Comment: @David Speyer  Thanks.  LLL is a good idea.
$(\sqrt5-1)/2$ is too small but the next one works quickly:
$1-x-x^2+x^4-x^5+x^7+x^8 = (1-x+x^2) (1-x^2-x^3)^2$.


Comment: The only other example with degree $\le 10$ is 
$1-z-{z}^{3}-{z}^{5}+{z}^{6}+{z}^{8}+{z}^{9}+{z}^{10}= \left( {z}^{2}+1
 \right)  \left( {z}^{2}-z+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{3}+{z}^{2}-1
 \right) ^{2}
$

Comment: LLL??????? Take a monic $p\in\mathbb Z[x]$. Consider $P(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx^k$ with $a_k=0,\pm 1$. Look at its remainder modulo $p^2$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$. Its coefficients are of the kind $\sum_z \sum_k a_k(c_z z^k+d_zkz^k)$ where $z$ runs over the roots of $p$ (interpolation). We need just to have $\sum_k a_k z^k$ and $\sum_k a_k kz^k$ less than fixed $\delta>0$ for all $z$ to get zero remainder. $\{-1,0,1\}$ is the difference set of $\{0,1\}$. We have $2^n$ options and $Cn\max(|z|,1)^{2n}$ boxes for each $z$ plus conjugation symmetry, so for $p(z)=z^3+z^2-1$ we win just by Dirichlet.  

Comment: @fedja Not sure if you're asking what LLL is, or expressing disbelief at my naivety in using it. LLL is an algorithm for finding short vectors in a lattice. What I was doing computationally was computing $x^k \mod p^2$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$, computing the null space of that matrix, and then looking for short vectors in that lattice. I thought it would be easier than storing the $2^n$ elements necessary for the pigeonhole argument. On the other hand, I had not realized that we win automatically when $\max(z)^2 < 2$; that's a very nice insight.

Comment: Can we get $2^n$ down to $3^{n/2}$ by arbitrarily dividing the exponents into two equal groups?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. The argument of fedja seems to suggest we could get a `$\{ -1, 0, 1 \}$` polynomial with a root at $\sqrt[3]{2}$, but that's impossible because $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not a unit. I think your count of boxes should be $C n \max(|z|, 1)^{2 \deg p n}$

Comment: David, you have to count right: real roots do not provide conjugation symmetry and the other 2 roots of $z^3-2$ are of size $\sqrt[3]2$ as well, giving the total of $2^{4/3}>2$ for the base of the exponent. On the other hand, with $z^2+z^3-1$, we have 1 real root $s$ on $(0,1)$ and two conjugate complex roots whose squares of absolute value are $s^{-1}$. So, you can get even a quadruple root with this factor since $s^2>1/2$. As to LLL, I just lamented about the modern habit to rush to the computer instead of spending an hour or two with pen and paper :). 

Answer (score 5):

At least the set-theoretical question can be answered: the are the cardinality of the continuum many such series, as can be deduced from the results in this paper (not all of them attributed by the authors to themselves):

MR2293600 (2007k:30003) Reviewed 
Shmerkin, Pablo(FIN-JVS-MS); Solomyak, Boris(1-WA)
Zeros of {−1,0,1} power series and connectedness loci for self-affine sets. (English summary) 
Experiment. Math. 15 (2006), no. 4, 499–511.

Comment: I would guess that you probably mean, more speciically, continuum many? 

Comment: @Joel: Yes, that is a more precise statement, will fix.

Comment: Thank You Igor Rivin. I have thought so. But the measuretheortical question remains open, so I do not click the question as answered. I guess the measure of the set is small (0?) but I have no idea to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

Some more examples with polynomials:

$$\matrix{\left( {z}^{6}+{z}^{5}-{z}^{3}+z+1 \right)  \left( z+{z}^{4}-1 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{8}+{z}^{7}-{z}^{5}-{z}^{4}-{z}^{3}+z+1 \right)  \left( z+
{z}^{6}-1 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{9}+{z}^{8}-{z}^{6}-{z}^{5}-{z}^{4}-{z}^{3}+z+1 \right) 
 \left( z+{z}^{7}-1 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{4}-{z}^{3}+{z}^{2}-z+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{2}+{z}^{5}-1
 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{6}-{z}^{5}+{z}^{4}-{z}^{3}+{z}^{2}-z+1 \right)  \left( {z
}^{2}+{z}^{7}-1 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{6}-{z}^{5}+{z}^{3}-z+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{3}+{z}^{4}-1
 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{7}-{z}^{5}+{z}^{4}+{z}^{3}-{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {z}^
{3}+{z}^{5}-1 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( -{z}^{10}+{z}^{8}-{z}^{7}+{z}^{6}+{z}^{5}-2\;{z}^{4}+{z}^{3}-z
+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{3}+{z}^{7}-1 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{4}-{z}^{3}+{z}^{2}-z+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{4}+{z}^{5}-1
 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{4}-{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{4}+{z}^{6}-1 \right) ^{
2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{6}-{z}^{5}+{z}^{4}-{z}^{3}+{z}^{2}-z+1 \right)  \left( {z
}^{4}+{z}^{7}-1 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{8}-{z}^{7}+{z}^{5}-{z}^{4}+{z}^{3}-z+1 \right)  \left( {z
}^{5}+{z}^{6}-1 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{6}-{z}^{5}+{z}^{4}-{z}^{3}+{z}^{2}-z+1 \right)  \left( {z
}^{6}+{z}^{7}-1 \right) ^{2}\cr
\left( -{z}^{14}-{z}^{13}-2\;{z}^{12}-{z}^{11}+{z}^{9}+2\;{z}^{8}-2\;{z}^{5}+2\;{z}^{2}+z+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{5}-{z}^{3}+{z}^{2}+z-1
 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{5}+{z}^{4}-{z}^{3}-{z}^{2}+z+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{5}+{z
}^{3}-{z}^{2}+z-1 \right) ^{2}\cr
 \left( {z}^{15}+{z}^{14}-{z}^{11}-{z}^{10}+{z}^{9}+{z}^{8}+{z}^{7}+{z
}^{6}-{z}^{5}-{z}^{4}+z+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{5}-{z}^{4}+{z}^{3}+z-1
 \right) ^{2}\cr
}$$

Comment: With LLL or some other method?  Any luck finding a triple root?

Comment: See my remark above plus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_conjecture 

Comment: @Noam  Modify your earlier result to get as many roots as you want:
$p(y) = (1-x+x^2) (1-x^2-x^3)^2$ where $x=y^n$.

Comment: @Marc: Yes, but that's still some number of double roots,
and I asked for a triple root.  Can you find a
$\lbrace -1, 0, 1 \rbrace$ polynomial divisible by the cube of a
non-cyclotomic polynomial?


Comment: No triple roots yet...

Comment: LLL finally turned up a few triple roots, namely multiples of
$(1-x^2-x^3)^3$ such as
$$
1 - x - x^2 - x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^8 - x^9 + x^{10} - x^{11} - x^{14} 
- x^{16} + x^{17} - x^{18} - x^{19} - x^{21} - x^{22} 
\phantom{etc}
$$ 
$$ 
\phantom{etc} - x^{23} - x^{25} + x^{26} + x^{27} - x^{28} - x^{30} - x^{31} - x^{32} - x^{33} - x^{34} - x^{35} - x^{36} - x^{37} + x^{38} - x^{40} - x^{41}.
$$

Comment: Ah, after adjusting my program I found some too, such as
$$
\matrix{{z}^{19}-{z}^{18}+{z}^{17}-{z}^{16}+{z}^{15}+{z}^{14}-{z}^{13}+{z}^{12
}-{z}^{11}\cr+{z}^{10}-{z}^{9}+{z}^{8}-{z}^{7}+{z}^{6}-{z}^{5}-{z}^{4}+{z
}^{3}-{z}^{2}+z-1\cr= \left( {z}^{7}+2\;{z}^{6}+{z}^{5}-{z}^{2}-2\;z-1
 \right)  \left( {z}^{4}-{z}^{3}+{z}^{2}-z+1 \right) ^{3}}
$$

Comment: What I was using was integer linear programming.  Given polynomial $p(z)$ of degree $m$, find integers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ that satisfy the constraints that the coefficients of each power of $z$ in $p(z)(1 + a_1 z + \ldots + a_n z^n$ are all $\ge -1$ and $\le 1$.

Comment: $z^4 - z^3 + z^2 - z + 1$ is a cyclotomic polynomial (factor of $z^5+1$)
so it's easy to get an arbitrarily large power, e.g. by multiplying it
by $\prod_{j=1}^m ((z^5)^{2^j} - 1)$.  The problem is very different for
non-cyclotomic factors.


Answer (score 0):

I am going to address the question for $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ measures, using probabilistic language. This is not a complete answer, but I am trying to relate your question to the properties of the distribution of $f(x)$. Clearly, for $x<1/2$ we never even reach zero, but my guess is that for $x>1/2$ this distribution is absolutely continuous, though I am unable to prove this at the moment.

So formally, at least,

$$\displaystyle \mathsf{E} \, \sum_{f(x)=0} \mathsf{1}\{|f^\prime(x)| < \epsilon\} = \intop_0^1 \mathsf{E} \, \delta(f(x)) \mathsf{1}\{|f(x)|<\epsilon\} |f^\prime(x)| dx \le \epsilon \intop_0^1 \mathsf{E} \, \delta(f(x)) dx.$$

$\mathsf{E} \, \delta$ is the density at zero, and it can be made perfect sense of, provided that the law of $f(x)$ has continuous density at zero. I don't know whether it has continuous density, but if we manage to prove that $f(x)$ has at least bounded density for $x>1/2$, then we can write inequalities with approximations of $\delta$ to get the same results...

Comment: Dear Alexander Shamov,


thansk for Your idea, but i do not see clear in the moment if it works this way...

Best

Jörg Neunhäuserer